# Sending image value to second form in php

Tags: php

I have the following scenario -

User clicks on an image to search for a particular brand vehicle. The value of that image must then go the hidden box where I will post the value returned to another form. I just can't seem to get the value returned...

My code...

```
<form action="searchbrand.php" method="POST" name="frmbrand">
 <!--First row of logos...-->   
 <table class="whitelogo">
  <tr>
    <td align="center">
        <p style="height:5px"></p>
        <input type="image" name="brand" id="brand" value="Alfa Romeo" src="images/carlogos/alfa.jpg" height="55px" width="55px" title="View our Alfa Romeo Selection" alt="Alfa Romeo" onClick="javascript:document.submitForm.submit();" />
    </td>
    <td align="center">
        <p style="height:5px"></p>
        <input type="image" name="brand" id="brand" value="Aston Martin" src="images/carlogos/aston.jpg" height="55px" width="55px" title="View our Aston Martin Selection" alt="Aston Martin" onClick="javascript:document.submitForm.submit();" />
    </td>
    <td align="center">
        <p style="height:5px"></p>
        <input type="image" name="brand" id="brand" value="Audi" src="images/carlogos/audi.gif" height="55px" width="55px" title="View our Audi Selection" alt="Audi" onClick="javascript:document.submitForm.submit();" />
    </td>
    <td align="center">
        <p style="height:5px"></p>
        <input type="image" name="brand" id="brand" value="Bentley" src="images/carlogos/bentley.jpg" height="55px" width="55px" title="View our Bentley Selection" alt="Bentley" onClick="javascript:document.submitForm.submit();" />
    </td>
    <td align="center">
        <p style="height:5px"></p>
        <input type="image" name="brand" id="brand" value="BMW" src="images/carlogos/bmw.gif" height="55px" width="55px" title="View our BMW Selection" alt="BMW" onClick="javascript:document.submitForm.submit();" />
    </td>
    <td align="center">
        <p style="height:5px"></p>
        <input type="image" name="brand" id="brand" value="Cadillac" src="images/carlogos/cadillac.jpg" height="55px" width="55px" title="View our Cadillac Selection" alt="Cadillac" onClick="javascript:document.submitForm.submit();" />
    </td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

As you will notice here I have named the images ALL 'brand' with seperate values for each.

```
 <input type="hidden" name="hidbrand" value="<?=$_POST['brand'];?>"/>
 </form>
```

I'm trying to capture the value here from whichever image user clicked on...

In my searchbrand.php page, which will then do stuff according to the returned value, the following...

```
 <?php
 include 'init.php';
 $vehicle_brand = $_POST['hidbrand'];
 echo $vehicle_brand, '</br>';
 ?>
```

Nothing gets returned, no error, no value, all blank like me :)
Anyone have an idea where I'm going haywire?

Comment: Matter of interest, when I view the page source code, I can see the correct returned value in the hidden box, i.e BMW if the user clicked on the "BMW" Image.

Comment: Check the value of file_get_contents('php://input'). I had an issue where $_POST came up empty, but if it's there, you can still access it.

Comment: I've already tested that theory, thanx. There is definitely no value carried over. Atkins might be right, it seems that the form is submitted before the value is added to the hidden input.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Remove `<?=$_POST['brand']?>` from hidbrand and replace onClick in all of the image input types with this:

```
javascript:document.forms['frmbrand'].hidbrand.value = this.value;
```

This will simply fill the hidden element with the value of the image the user has clicked on and then automatically submit the form.

The current javascript you're using in the onClick at the moment (submitting the form) is moot and isn't needed, as image input types automatically submit the form when clicked on.

Comment: Thank you Beardy, exactly what was required, problem solved. I've learned something here, never knew that an image is an auto submit button on its own, where the entire problem started... thank you so much!! :)

Answer (score 3):

Please give different id to images.In one page the name can be same for form element.But id should be unique to each form element.
If you give same name to more than 1 element then it will return array as post value.
You can get the values by using jquery like

```
    $('input[name="brand"]').onclick(function(){alert($(this).attr('alt'));}
```

This will alert the alt attribute of image on which user clicked.

Just use [var_dump()](https://www.php.net/var_dump)  to see what's in $_POST :

```
var_dump($_POST);
```

And you'll see that, when your form is submitted using the `input type="image">`

This will return array something like

`array 'brand_x' => string '0' (length=1) 'brand_y' => string '0' (length=1)`'

So that you can use `$_POST[brand_x]` to get the values on the second form

Comment: Thank you Hemant, currently I do not seem to have a problem getting the value, the problem seems to be the value returned AFTER the form was submitted, resulting in an empty value carried over to my second page.

Answer (score 1):

When you click on an image input, it submits the form, so it's probably submitting before the value of hidinput is set.

Have a look at what's included in $_POST - IIRC, you'll get values sent corresponding to the x and y positions that were clicked on the image. You can use this to tell which image was clicked, without having to do any Javascript to do it.

Comment: This makes sense... It seems it adds the value to the hidden input after submission. How would I go about adding the value first and then submit the form? I will have a look at the coordinates functions as well if that will solve my problem, thanx.

Answer (score 1):

When I understand you correctly, this should be an example:

```
<!doctype html>
<html><head></head>
<body>
    <form action="searchbrand.php" method="POST"
        name="frmbrand" onsubmit="return false;">
        <input type="image" name="brand" id="brand" value="Alfa Romeo" 
            src="images/carlogos/alfa.jpg" height="55px" width="55px" 
            title="View our Alfa Romeo Selection" alt="Alfa Romeo" 
            onClick="document.submitForm.hidbrand.value=this.value; document.submitForm.submit();" />
    </form>
    <form action="http://www.stackoverflow.com/" method="POST" name="submitForm">
        <input type="text" name="hidbrand" value="" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

First cancel the submit on the form containing the images:

```
... onsubmit="return false;" ...
```

Then copy the value to the hidden field in the *submitForm* before submitting it (in my example I didn't hide the *hidbrand* field for debugging purposes):

```
... onClick="document.submitForm.hidbrand.value=this.value; document.submitForm.submit();" ...
```

The first form doesn't actually have to be a form as it shouldn't be submitted. You can use plain images with *onclick* handlers.

Comment: This seemed like the solution. If I just add the value part and delete the submit part, I get a echo out on my first page with teh correct value. Once I've added the submit part again, no value was returned. I'm stumped... :)

Comment: My problem is that I do not want to add a submit button at all, I would like the user to click on ONE image and they will be shown the adverts from that particular manufacturer, hence my code for submission in the image input. I've checked the value in source code and did show the value. It seems to be adding the value though AFTER form submission.

Comment: Thank you Flansch. I've used Beardy's solution, much quicker adn sooo simple. You show some huge effort, thank you again!!! :)